# How do I create nuget package and update metadata for C++/CLI vcxproj project

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-c++, nuget, c++-cli

I have created C++/CLI project to wrap native library. How can I create nuget package using powershell command to add this wrapper library as well as native C++ dll it wraps.
I can see some posts for how to use nuget packages in C++/CLI projects but cannot find anything useful for actually creating nuget package for C++/CLI project itself. Nuget.exe "pack" command fails for .vcxproj project.

The NuGet.exe will automatically replace metadata like id, version etc from assembly/csproj file but we are not using vcxproj to build nuget package for C++ CLI project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using nuspec file directly while building the library from bamboo itself. I used bamboo to set the build version of the metadata. All other metadata is hardcoded in the nuspec file which does not need to change with every build.

& "NuGet.exe" pack "Library.nuspec" -Version ${bamboo.BuildVersion} -OutputDirectory ${bamboo.build.working.directory}